# Как преобразовать строку в ссылку на словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, есть словарь:

```
some_dict = {
    "one": "Someone",
    "two": "Another one",
    "three": {
        "three_1": "Its three, not free!",
        "three_2": "Already said it"
    },
    "four": {
        "four_1": "Four 4 u",
        "four_2": {
            "four_2_1": "What is it",
            "four_2_2": "OMG!"
        }
    }
}
```

Есть пример пользовательского ввода:

```
four/four2/four2_1
```

Как сделать так, что бы в ответ на ввод, программа выдала значение `some_dict["four"]["four_2"]["four_2_1"]`, либо любое другое значение, в зависимости от ввода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделяем строку по слешам и последовательно движемся по уровням словаря

```
s = 'four/four_2/four_2_1'

d = some_dict    
try:
    for i in s.split('/'):
        d = d[i]
    print(d)
except KeyError:
    print('No such path')
```

Comment: Только дошло, хотел уже сам ответить на вопрос ).

Answer (score 1):

вариант с рекурсией:

```
keys = 'four/four_2/four_2_1'

def f(x,d):
    if len(x)==1: return d.get(x[0]) or 'No key'
    return f(x[1:],d[x[0]]) if x[0] in d else 'No key'

f(keys.split('/'), some_dict)  # 'What is it'
```